# Where I should put a comma in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

where I should put a comma in this sentence?

Thank you for inspiring us to be a better servant of God.

Comment: Why do you think it needs a comma?

Comment: some say that you should put a comma after Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere. The sentence does not require one.

Putting a comma after "Thank you" would *only* be acceptable - and even then, not necessary - for stylistic effect in certain circumstances, e.g. if you were beginning several sentences with "Thank you".